# Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript' in AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, appdelegate

I'm migrating my Swift code from version 2 to 3. In my AppDelegate.swift I have the following method being implemented:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject : AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

    // error below this line
    if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    } else {}
    return true
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Ambiguous reference to member 'subscript'

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Usually it's because you did `something[somethingelse]`, but you didn't specified to the compiler that `something` can use `[]` (subscript). Also, your method is not Swift 3: Check there: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1622921-application for the "Swift3 compliant one".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following @Larme recommendations I solved the issue by changing the method signature to:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,
                          didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool {

    FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)

// error below this line
    if let notification = launchOptions?[UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey.remoteNotification] as? [NSObject : AnyObject] {
    } else {}
    return true
}
```